# Getting values to show in a single row from a one to many relationship in Crystal Reports

Tags: variables, crystal-reports, one-to-many

I need to show all the children and their birthdays connected to a record in a single row.

Output needs to be like this with each child in a separate column in one row:

NAME      CHILD_1   CHILD_2   CHILD_3   CHILD_4  CHILD_5   CHILD_6    CHILD_7

Tom Smith  Sally     Suzie    Sandy      Cindy   Simon     Sinbad

Dan Jones  Bobby     Billy

Tina Yu    Lillian   Meaghan   Timmy

My table CHILDREN's Table contains:

`ID (of the parent)`, `SEQN`, `First Name`, `Birthday`

I can't seem to find a way to show whatever children they have in the same row.

Comment: Use cross tab in crystal reports

Comment: Hi Siva, I've been trying as you suggested to use a cross tab. I can't seem to make it work as it wants to summarize the children's name. And the other issue I have is that I need Child1, Child1Birthday, Child2, Child2 Birthday, Child3 etc... While I can get the children's names to show across the top in labels, I think can't get their corresponding birthday. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you show the screenshot of your design and crosstab expert?